# Parse Cloud Code: beforeSave query return code not working

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

any ideas why my snippet does not seem to go into the branches of the query.find() function after the result is retrieved?

```js
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("AccountTest", function(request, response) {
  var email = request.object.get("email");
  var accountTest = new Parse.Object.extend("AccountTest");
  var query = new Parse.Query(accountTest);
  console.log(email);
  query.equalTo("email",email);
  query.find({
      success: function(results) {
        console.log("checking");
        if (results.length == 0) {
          console.log("SUCCESS");
          response.success();
        }else{
          console.log("FAIL");
          response.error("E-mail has already been used");
        }
        console.log('no branch taken');
      },
      error: function() {
        response.error("Something went wrong with the query");
      }
  });
  console.log("OUT OF SCOPE")
  response.error("Something went wrong");
});
```

The log on parse.com logs the email and "OUT OF SCOPE" and "Something went wrong" but it never goes in the success or error branch, any ideas? I can't figure out what's going wrong with the query.find() function.

Comment: what kind of object is AccountTest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the asynchronous nature of `find` function! Your `beforeSave` code hits the last line `response.error` before the `find` function gets a change to complete. When you call your `find` function it returns immediately because of its asynchronous nature. Its callback will only be called when it has completed. If you simply remove your last line `response.error("Something went wrong");` your function should work as intended.

Comment: No problem, I also suggest you change you code to use Promises instead of using Backbone style success/error callbacks. Your code will be more readable when it comes to asynchronous behaviour

Answer (score 0):

You dont need the *new* keyword to extend an Object.

```
var accountTest = new Parse.Object.extend("AccountTest");
```

should be

```
 var accountTest =  Parse.Object.extend("AccountTest");
```

followed by the rest of your code, which is correct.

Also,

```
var email = request.object.get("email");
```

The above line will get the mail field from the request object. The object has not yet been saved into the DB. So, there are no matching records. Hence, it will not go to the find block. If you try saving an object with the value of email field that already exists, then your code , along with the above mentioned change will work.

Comment: That did not solve my problem.. It is still not going into the branch

Comment: In that case have you tried to check if, you have a result matching the query in your Parse DB ?

Comment: At first the db was empty so I created a record.. so the query should return at least one record because of the matching email field

Comment: var email = request.object.get("email");

Comment: That's what I said, I already created the record in my db with an email field that has the same value that I'm using in request. So the find function should return at least one result..

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing AccountTest might be user objects. If this is correct, try adding

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
```

before executing the query.

Comment: No they are not user objects, just some fields.